# Написание хранимой процедуры PostgreSQL, обьединяющей таблицы разделенных по дате

Tags: postgresql, хранимые-процедуры

Есть триггер, который создает таблицы по датам (каждый день новая таблица) поступаюших данных. Нужно написать процедуру, которая принимает два параметра: начало и конец даты, затем обьединяющая данные из этих таблиц, соответствующих промежутку этих дат.
Например, есть таблицы с 01.01.2020 по 20.01.2020. Поступает запрос на процедуру с 03.01.2020 по 05.01.2020, она должна обьединить таблицы с 03.01.2020 по 05.01.2020 и вернуть его.

Comment: Надо переделать подход к хранению данных и хранить все в одной таблице. Потому как SQL не предназначен для работы с динамически изменяемым списком таблиц. В крайнем случае вы конечно можете воспользоваться динамическим sql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ecpg-dynamic.html что бы строить запрос на лету и сразу его выполнять

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам функция? Вы как-то странно пытаетесь переизобрести партицирование. Используйте собственно партицирование.

Предположим у вас есть таблица `something_20200218` с полем `created_at timestamp` с датой. В этой таблице лежат данные только за `2020-02-18`

```
create table something (like something_20200218) partitioning by range (created_at);
alter table something attach partition something_20200218 
   for values from ('2020-02-18') to ('2020-02-19');
```

Аналогичными `attach partition` подключаете остальные разделы.

```
select .. from something where created_at >= '2020-01-03' and created_at < '2020-01-06'
```

И всё, никакие функции вам не нужны. Даже не упоминая о разнице в производительности.

PS: postgresql 10 и новее. Для более старых версий - схожим образом через механизм наследования таблиц.